# Adjusting hard values in processing for any screen size

Tags: image, resize, processing, resolution, screen-resolution

So I'm making a game with my group on processing for a project and we all have different computers. The problem is we built the game on one computer, however at this point we have realized the the `(1200,800)` size we used does not work on our professors computer. Unfortunately we have hard coded thousands of values to fit on this resolution. Is there any way to make it fit on all computers?

From my own research I found you can use `screen.width` and `screen.height` in order to get the size of the screen, I set the game window to about half the screen size. However all the images I had loaded for background and stuff are 1200x800 So I am unsure how to go about modifying ALL of my pictures (backgrounds), and hard values.

Is there anyway to fix this without having to go manually change the 1000's of hard values? (Yes I am fully aware how bad it is I hard coded the numbers).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As mentioned in title, the language is processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you have learned your lesson about hard-coding numbers, I won't say anything about it :)

You may have heard of embedding a processing PApplet inside a traditional java JFrame or similar. If you are okay with scaling the image that your PApplet draws (ie it draws it at the resolution that you've coded, and then the resulting image is scaled up or down to match the screen), then you could embed your papplet in a frame, capture the papplet's output to an image, scale the image, then draw it to the screen. A quick googling yielded [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123686/resize-drawing-to-match-frame-size). It may make your game look funny if the resolutions are too different, but this is a quick and dirty way. It's possible that you'll want to have this done in a separate thread, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824756/awt-custom-rendering-capture-smooth-resizes-and-eliminate-resize-flicker).

Having said that, I do not recommend it. One of the best thing (IMO) of Processing is not having to mess directly with AWT/Swing. It's also a messy kludge and the "right thing to do" is just to go back and change the hard-coded numbers to variables. For your images, you can use [PImage's resize()](http://processing.org/reference/PImage_resize_.html). You say your code is several hundred lines long, but in reality that isn't a huge amount-- the best thing to do is just to suck it up and be unhappy for a few hours. Good luck!